# Qt thread does not work

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

i've two object from different classes: "master" and "slave".
i tried to create a thread in master.cpp where i've declared the slave object.
The problem is that the thread does not start

```
QThreadEx daqThread;
daqSlave daqslv;
daqslv.doSetup(daqThread);
daqslv.moveToThread(&daqThread);
daqThread.start(QThread::NormalPriority);
```

where: doSetup() is:

```
 void daqSlave::doSetup(QThreadEx &cThread) const
{
   qDebug()<<"daqSlave::doSetup()-begin";
   QObject::connect(&cThread, SIGNAL(started()),
                     this, SLOT(avvio()));
   qDebug()<<"daqSlave::doSetup()-end";
 }
```

"doSetup()" works but "avvio()" doesn't.
Can anyone explain me why?
Thank you,
Alessia

Comment: Does your type `daqSlave` inherits from `QObject`?

Comment: Where did you put `daqThread` initialization? Are you aware that `daqThread` will be destoroyed once control flow leaves that block?

Comment: What is `QThreadEx`? Did you use 'Q_OBJECT' macro in your `daqSlave ` class.

Comment: Note that subclassing QThread (which you seem to be doing) is often a wrong way to do threading in Qt. QThread is a thread *controller/manager*, and subclassing it easily leads to code running in wrong OS thread. If you don't know how that might happen and therefore how to avoid it, don't subclass QThread ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues:

- The `QThread` and `daqSlave` instances are going out of scope. Use `new` and give the thread a parent object. `moveToThread()` automatically re-parents daqSlv to the thread, so this is not a concern.
- The `doSetup()` function is called before you've moved your worker to the thread. Specify `Qt::QueuedConnection` In your call to `QObject::connect()` to fix this.